# Knockoutjs Editable Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Are there any samples or examples of standard Grids/tables created by Knockoutjs that are sortable on their columns and editable on a row level.

That is the rows are a normal table until you click and then you can edit them and save them back to the server using Ajax? Is there any examples of integrating Knockout with for example a JQuery UI editable grid like Wijmo grid or any other. I guess any JS grid that takes JSON could work?

I have a requirement to implement an editable table and would rather use Knockoutjs. Especially with Upshot.js and MVC4 on the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[KoGrid](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid) is a pretty good option.

It allows you to define cell and row templates where you can do exactly what you're saying. There is some documentation on the [wiki](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/wiki/Custom-Templates)

Comment: Looks awesome. So I would just add my own functionality to support clicking on an edit icon and making the row editable?

Comment: Yep - if you run into more questions just open an issue on GH or ask here

Answer (score 0):

There are also various Knockout addons for datatables discussion here http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4969/knockoutjs/p1 and the implementation here http://www.joshbuckley.co.uk/2011/07/knockout-js-datatable-bindings/

Wijmo recently added support for Knockout in v2.1 of their framework a example can be seen here http://wijmo.com/grid-with-knockout-viewmodel-loading-remote-data/

Also Kendo UI can easily integrate with Knockout

New version of datatables 1.10 is going to have support